# React/Redux project giving me the error 'Failed to compile. Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory''

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

This is the component triggering the error:

**TodoList.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Task from './Task';

const TodoList = (props) => {
  const tasks = props.tasks.map((task, i) => <Task task={task} key={i} index={i} />);
  return (
    <ul>
      { tasks }
    </ul>
  );
};

export default TodoList;
```

What's incorrect in how I'm exporting the component that would cause it to not be found when compiling?

Comment: Have you checked that your Task component is in the same directory as your TodoList component?

Comment: Yup, it is in fact in the same directory.

Comment: Are you using webpack? Are you resolving the extension?

Comment: Also have you installed react e.g. "npm install react" or "yarn add react"?

Answer (score 0):

```
import Task from './Task';
```

try

```
import Task from './Task.js';
```

Or

```
import Task from './Task.jsx';
```

if using jsx files